# How to print a few Strings under the other?

Tags: java, string, swing

When I make `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, abc)` it prints those 2 strings side by side but I want to print them one under the other. How can I do that?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class abc {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String abc ="Highschool 1" + "Highschool 2";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, abc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
String abc = "Highschool 1" + "\n" + "Highschool 2";
```

`\n` is the newline character and will make a new line after `Highschool 1`

Comment: Glad I could help, you should accept the answer if it answers the question :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use HTML (basically, HTML 3.2) which is way cool because you can add color and other formatting:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String msg = "<html><font color='red'>hello</font><br><big>goodbye</big></html>";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String abc ="Highschool 1" + "\n" + "Highschool 2";
```

`\n` is the carriage return character.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to use the new line regular expression which is `"\n"`

```
String abc ="Highschool 1" + "\n" + "Highschool 2";
```

If you printed abc it would be:

```
Highschool 1
Highschool 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be **concatenation** with String api

**Just to give you another flavor**

Code:

```
  public class LambdaTest     
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
         String s1 = "Highschool 1";
         String s2 = "Highschool 2";

         String s = s1.concat("\n" + s); <-- \n That means a new line is printed
         System.out.println(s);
    } 
}
```

Another way would be just to print each of them in each line and use println

Code:

```
  System.out.println("HighSchool 1");<-- \n That means a new line is printed
                                            It is implicit in println function 
  System.out.println("HighSchool 2");
```

output:

```
Highschool 1
Highschool 2
```